# How to pass nginx variables (data) to already built frontend application

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, frontend

I'm new with nginx and docker. I would be extremely grateful for your advice.

I want to use nginx `ngx_http_geoip_module` and data which I'll get with this module I would like to pass to the frontend application for the next manipulation. Also I expect that data will depend of user's country.

Is it possible (and how) **to pass dynamic data from nginx to already built frontend application** (I use Angular 9 in this case)?

Comment: Could you make a specific URL for getting this information, call it from the frontend and return something like `return 200 $my_variable;`?

Comment: @Audiopolis Thanks for the answer. At the moment this is really my solution to this problem, but I just want to know if it is possible to get data from nginx

Comment: I think it should be possible to modify query string and add this data as additional query argument of the request. Can you show your `server` block from nginx config?

Comment: @IvanShatsky it looks like this 
```server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain;
   
    location ~ path/to/it {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param FOO "bar";
    }
}```

Comment: What you show looks like config for PHP-FPM, I don't understand how angular app can be served with this. Anyway [here](https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module#example-usage) is example of passing geoip data to backend via `fastcgi_param` directive.